# JAXB XmlAnyElement set namespace attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a simple Java class I am annotating with JAXB:

```
class Foo {
   @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
   List<Object> any;
}
```

Which produces the following schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="foo">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is there any way to set the namespace attribute for the `<any>` element, so that it generates like:

```
<xs:any namespace="##targetNamespace" processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Comment: any luck finding the awnser on this one?

Answer (score 1):

insert a package-info.java file into your foo class package with contents like :

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:foo:v1", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package java.ns.foo;
```